# how to add ~ and | in a character variable in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode6, nsstring

Swift produce an error when I'm try to compare ~ (tilde) or | (pipe) with a character in `NSString` object

**Communicator.swift:63:48**: Invalid character in source file
and many other places
 [image: error produced by swift]

what i am thinking that it may be conflict with | operator or ~ operator so it don't allow me to do so
how can I escape it if possible or what should i do to solve this 
i am using `Xcode 6.2` and i am new to swift and IOS.

REMARK : M know very well how to compare string etc the problem is with ~ (tild) and | pipe character whenever i compare with them swift produce error plzzzzz first see the image i uploaded and this question is not duplicate of anyone m spend my 4 to 5 hours in searching solution of this in verious swift blogs and google fb,google groups and etc place also searched in stackoverflow too but m can't find the solution then i ask hear so please not about it before comment answer or vote minus my code take at least a second in see what i exactly  asked to you
thank you

Comment: In your case, you should use something like ``Character(UnicodeScalar(data.characterAtIndex(0))) == "~"``

Comment: @Werner Kvalem Vesterås this question is not duplicate of any other the main problem with tilde ~ m know well how to compare 2 things

Comment: This is not Java, swift doesn't use single quotes for characters. That's why you have errors `Invalid character in source file`. There is no problem with tildes.

Comment: its not problem of single quote @Sulthan

Comment: its the problem of unicode anyway m solved it thank you @WernerKvalemVesterås

Comment: @IndrajitSinhRayjada Your screenshot is showing a clear problem with single quotes.

Answer (score -3):

I have found the answer myself, just change following

```
String(UnicodeScalar(data.characterAtIndex(0))) == "~"
```